# All instances upgrade from Command Prompt

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, upgrade, command-line

I want to create a cmd script to upgrade sql servers in the organization(mostly 2014) to 2016. I've read Microsoft documentation 
[Install SQL Server 2016 from the Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.130).aspx) regarding this issue.
The problem is that there is no option written there to upgrade all server instances like there is in installing updates: [Installing Updates from the Command Prompt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638066(v=sql.130).aspx) using `/allinstances`.
Is there any way to auto upgrade all instances on the server using one command line?

Comment: I don't think it is possible because no such option exist. Installing instances piecemeal gives you more control

Answer (score 0):

With SQL 2019 (and beyond I presume) the syntax needs to be:
(e.g.)

```
SQLServer2019-KB5033688-x64.exe /qs 
/IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms 
/Action=Patch /AllInstances
```

A little hidden tidbit from MS, but it works.....perhaps this can be of help to others

Comment: Isn't that just an _update_? The question is asking for a way to do a version-to-version _upgrade_.

Answer (score -1):

You can first download the SQL server 20XX edition of your needs [here](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-ch/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).
Then you can download and extract the local content media on your machine.
After that you should see in the downloaded folder the `SETUP.EXE` file
Then you can open the command prompt and type (By considering your sql standard instance name is MSSQLSERVER):

```
C:\Path_to_file\SETUP.EXE /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=UPGRADE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
```

When you connect to your database, you should see the new version installed
. In my case I upgraded from SQL server 2017 to SQL server 2019. Old Maj version was 14.XX, now the new Maj version is 15.XX. See below.

[image: SQL server 2019 version]

And there are plenty of cool explanations on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15)

EDIT: I think its not possible to upgrade all instances at one with the `allinstances` parameter, because not allowed (Tried it).
Here is what the command line says:

```
 ALLINSTANCES                 Specifies that all instances are to be included
                              in the Setup operation. This parameter is
                              supported only when applying a patch.
```

Bu you can loop with powershell on all your instances with the above command. If you dont have 1 million instances, it should be fine.

Comment: The question is about upgrading _all_ instances, not _one_ instance, isn't it.

Comment: I upgraded one instance, because I only have one. I tried the /Allinstances but its apparently not possible, because not allowed. It you have multiple instances I think you just can separate them with a "," like /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER, BLABLA1, BLABLA2 etc.. Or you can make a loop on your multiple instances with the executable, via powershell for better control.